# Height argument is not working with renderPlotly within shiny context

Tags: r, shiny, plotly

Using ggplot, I could create my desired plot. However, when I converted to plotly (the code below), I got an error:

```
Error in renderPlotly({ : unused argument (height = function() {
    400 + (length(workforce_data()[["County.y"]]) * 5)
}).
```

How can I fix this?

**plotly code**

```
output$workforce_plot <- renderPlotly ({
   workforce_plot()
 }  , height = function() {400 + (length(workforce_data()[["County.y"]]) *5) })
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`renderPlotly` doesn't have a `height` argument.

However, you can use `ggplotly`'s `height` argument as follows:

```
library(plotly)
library(shiny)

ui <- fluidPage(
  sliderInput("heightSlider", "Plot heigth [px]", min = 200L, max = 1000L, value = 500L),
  plotlyOutput("myPlot")
)

server <- function(input, output, session) {
  output$myPlot <- renderPlotly({
    p <- ggplot(data.frame(x = 1:10, y = runif(10)), aes(x, y)) + geom_point()
    ggplotly(p, height = input$heightSlider)
  })
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```